# Populate text fields on select field update in Flask / WTForms

Tags: javascript, flask, wtforms

Folks, scratching my head at this, there's a kind of an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488861/selectfield-option-to-dynamically-populate-default-value-in-textareafield-using), but having difficulty implementing it.

I currently have a recipe and styles table, and when submit an "add recipe" form, it copies data from the styles table into the recipe. What I would like to do is to select a style in the add recipe form and have this data populate form fields. So I'd like style-type for example to be populated in the form on updating the style select dropdown.

My set up:

**Routes:**

```
@app.route('/recipe/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def addrecipe():
    form = RecipeForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        recipe = Recipe(recipe_name=form.recipe_name.data, 
                        recipe_style=form.style.data.id,
                        style_name=form.style.data.name, 
                        style_type = form.style.data.type)
        db.session.add(recipe)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You added your recipe, get brewing!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('recipes'))
    return render_template('add_recipe.html', title = 'Add Recipe', form=form, legend='Add Recipe')
```

**Models:**

```
class Recipe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    recipe_style = db.Column(db.Text, db.ForeignKey('styles.id'))
    style_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    style_type = db.Column(db.String(100))


# used for query_factory    
def getStyles():
    return Styles.query.order_by(Styles.name.asc())
```

**Forms:**

```
class RecipeForm(FlaskForm):
    recipe_name = StringField('Recipe Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    style = QuerySelectField(query_factory=getStyles, 
                            get_label="name")
    style_type = StringField('Style Type')
```

**The Form HTML:**

```
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>
                <fieldset class="form-group card p-3 bg-light">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Overview</h5>
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        {{ form.recipe_name.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        {% if form.recipe_name.errors %}
                            {{ form.recipe_name(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.recipe_name.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.recipe_name(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group card p-3 bg-light">
                <h5 class="card-title">Style</h5>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        {{ form.style.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search Styles" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                        {% if form.style.errors %}
                            {{ form.style(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.style.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.style(class="form-control form-control-sm", id="style_name") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        {{ form.style_type.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        {% if form.style_type.errors %}
                            {{ form.style_type(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.style_type.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.style_type(class="form-control form-control-sm", id="styletype", style_type_tag='{{ form.style.data.type }}' ) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
```

**My Javascript so far:**

```
style_name.oninput = function(o) {
    // style = document.getElementById('styletype')
    styletype.value = $(o).attr('style_type_tag')
    }
```

I can get some basic stuff working with the JS function. So when I update the dropdown, it'll populate the field with some text. What I can't figure out is how to pull the style_type info from the database. The link at the top here loads that info into the html tags of the text box, but it's a little different to what I'm doing. The poster has looped through some items and it isn't a form. My *style_type_tag* is just showing up as the raw text. I'm guessing that the loop here is crucial but I can't quite make the step to getting into my setup.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was building a simple API. I'm sure there are simpler methods, but I wanted a bit of practice here and thought it would be useful in building other features into the project.

I followed Brad Traversy's [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTZiDnuC86g) on the subject and used the GET section to make this. His project was a simple single file project, so I had to get a bit more involved with imports etc in my project.

1. **Grab** [postman](https://postman.com/) to interact with the API
2. **Install Marshmallow**, To *requirements.txt*, add the lines:

```
flask-marshmallow
marshmallow-sqlalchemy
```

then run
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

3. **Import and initialise marshmallow.** In init.py:

```
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

4. **Add style schema** To *models.py*

```
# import module
from flaskblog import ma

# create schema with the fields required
class StyleSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "name", "origin", "type")

# initialise single style schema
style_schema = StyleSchema()
# initialise multiple style schema
styles_schema = StyleSchema(many=True)
```

Note that the `strict=True` isn't necessary any more with Marshmallow.

5. **Create endpoints/routes**, to *routes.py*:

```
# Get All Styles

@app.route('/styleget', methods=['GET'])
def styles_get():
    all_styles = Styles.query.all()
    result = styles_schema.dump(all_styles)
    # return jsonify(result.data) - note that this line is different to the video, was mentioned in the comments. Was originally "return jsonify(result.data)"
    return styles_schema.jsonify(all_styles)

# Get Single Product

# passes the id into the URL
@app.route('/styleget/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def style_get(id):
    style = Styles.query.get(id)
    return style_schema.jsonify(style)
```

6. **Update JS script**:

```
style_name.onchange = function() {
        // creates a variable from the dropdown
    style = document.getElementById('style_name').value
        // uses the variable to call the API and populate the other form fields
    fetch('/styleget/' + style).then(function(response) {
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        // this takes the 'type' data from the JSON and adds it to the styleType variable
        styleType = data.type;
        // adds the data from the variable to the form field using the ID of the form. 
        styletype.value = styleType
      });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same challenge!